# Work and kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

> A small object is placed at the top of an incline that is
>   essentially frictionless. The object slides down the incline
>   onto a rough horizontal surface, where it stops in 5.0 s
>   after traveling 60 m.
>
> (a) What is the speed of the object
>   at the bottom of the incline and its acceleration along the
>   horizontal surface?
>
> (b) What is the height of the incline?

I've been attempting this for a while and I'm just not sure if the question actually gives us enough information to actually solve it, any help would be great.

Comment: Yes, enough info is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has two parts:

**1)The part containing the temporal information about the motion**

You might have noticed that the horizontal surface is rough and hence a constant kinetic friction force acts (through which you might have noticed that the situation is for constant acceleration)  on the body to stop relative motion. Now think of the relevant kinematic equation which deals with final velocity $v_f$, displacement $s$, acceleration $a$ and time $t$ and then apply it to find the acceleration.

**2) Part devoid of the temporal information about the motion**

Here you must invoke the [work energy theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) to get the height.

Comment: By applying work energy theorem you would get a familiar kinematic equation which does not require time related information to solve.

Comment: thanks for all the help, I've been able to solve it now

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions